# Selecting multiple fields from row with max value of column, per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm quite certain I've painted myself into a corner and I can't figure my way out.

The Users table and OrderHistories tables both have 1+ million records:

```
SELECT
    u.Id ,
    u.Email AS EmailAddress ,
    c.Address_Address1 AS "Address 1" ,
    (
      SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            dbo.OrderHistories oh
        WHERE
            oh.UserId = u.UserName
    ) AS NumberOfOrders ,
    Carts.SubtotalAmount AS CartTotal ,
    (
      SELECT
            MAX(oh.CreateDate)
        FROM
            dbo.OrderHistories AS oh
        WHERE
            oh.UserId = u.Id
    ) AS LastOrderDate ,
    (
      SELECT
            LastOrders.SubtotalAmount AS LastOrderSubtotal
        FROM
            (
              SELECT
                    UserId ,
                    CreateDate ,
                    SubtotalAmount ,
                    MAX(CreateDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ) MyLastOrderDate
                FROM
                    Users u
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrderHistories oh
                    ON u.Id = oh.UserId
            ) AS LastOrders
        WHERE
            LastOrders.MyLastOrderDate = LastOrders.CreateDate
            AND LastOrders.UserId = u.Id
    ) AS LastOrderSubtotal
FROM
    Users u
    INNER JOIN Customers AS c
    ON u.Id = c.Id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Carts
    ON c.Id = Carts.CustomerId
```

This particular subquery is my current problem (EXTREMELY inefficient), but I'm not experienced enough to understand exactly why, or how I should be doing it instead (I can't get there from here!):

```
(
      SELECT
            LastOrders.SubtotalAmount AS LastOrderSubtotal
        FROM
            (
              SELECT
                    UserId ,
                    CreateDate ,
                    SubtotalAmount ,
                    MAX(CreateDate) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserId ) MyLastOrderDate
                FROM
                    Users u
                    INNER JOIN dbo.OrderHistories oh
                    ON u.Id = oh.UserId
            ) AS LastOrders
        WHERE
            LastOrders.MyLastOrderDate = LastOrders.CreateDate
            AND LastOrders.UserId = u.Id
    ) AS LastOrderSubtotal
```

Anyone mind telling me how terrible I am and then segue right into a suggested improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from looking at your query, you may be able to simplify it using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) like so:

```
select
    u.Id
  , EmailAddress = u.Email 
  , [Address 1]  = c.Address_Address1
  , CartTotal    = Carts.SubtotalAmount
  , NumberOfOrders = oh.NumberOfOrders
  , LastOrderDate  = oh.CreateDate
  , LastOrderSubtotal = oh.SubtotalAmount
from Users u
  inner join Customers AS c
    on u.Id = c.Id
  left join dbo.Carts
    on c.Id = Carts.CustomerId
  cross apply (
    select top 1
        i.CreateDate
      , i.SubtotalAmount
      , NumberOfOrders = count(*) over (partition by i.UserId) 
   from dbo.OrderHistories i
   where i.UserId = u.Id
   order by i.CreateDate desc
   ) as oh
```

If you want rows that may not have an `OrderHistory`, switch to `outer apply()`.

Reference:

- [**`apply()`** - msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [The power of T-SQL's APPLY operator - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/04/13/the-power-of-t-sqls-apply-operator/)
- [APPLY: It Slices! It Dices! It Does It All! - Brad Shulz](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2011/04/t-sql-tuesday-017-it-slices-it-dices-it.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will read the full documentation on APPLY and learn more about APPLY vs JOIN so I fully understand what I'm doing :)

Comment: @mynameisbear In addition to the documentation, this is a good read: [The power of T-SQL's APPLY operator - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/04/13/the-power-of-t-sql-s-apply-operator.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  I don't like cargo cult programming so this will help a bunch